# How to access AWS services on local machine(using eclipse)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
>       at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:371)

Answer (score 0):

The Error message itself self sufficient and the error message clearly explains that you had not set the `amazonAWSRegion` when you are building Amazon service client. As your question does not clearly depicts which AWS service your are trying to connect through your code, I have shown a sample example to build `AWS dynamoDB client`.

when you were building `AmazonDynamoDB` client instance use the below code sample.

```
String amazonAWSAccessKey = "yourAmazonAWSAccessKey";
String amazonAWSSecretKey = "yourAmazonAWSSecretKey";
String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint = "AmazonDynamoDBEndpoint";
String amazonAWSRegion = "amazonAWSRegion"; //(ex: us-east-1/us-west-1)
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey));
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder
                        .EndpointConfiguration(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint, amazonAWSRegion)).build();
```

If you want to connect the AWS service through Eclipse, the configuration setup is documented at [Set up AWS Toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html)